# Multiple occurrence in regex

Tags: regex

Suppose the following sequence: 0000000

I want to find all 0000 in the above sequence, if I use just `/0000/` regex it only matches the first, however, there are 4 occurrence of 0000 in the above sequence

How Can I find all of them by regex?

Ty!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a zero-width assertion such as positive lookahead and capture the results in a group, so the result won't be consumed after a match:

```regex
/(?=(0000))/g
```

See the [test case](https://regex101.com/r/gfFqy4/1/)

An example using JavaScript:

```js
const text = '0000000';

const regex = /(?=(0000))/g;

const result = [...text.matchAll(regex)].map(e => e[1]);

console.log(result);
```